# Mysql everyday crash

Tags: mysql, innodb

Mysql eats all the RAM and eventually disconnects. It works for about one day. At about 7 AM it goes down. Any pointers as to how to resolve this issue are very much appreciated.

mysql error.log file:

```
170912  7:52:56 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
170912  7:52:56 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170912  7:52:56 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170912  7:52:56 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
170912  7:52:56 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170912  7:52:56 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 300.0M
170912  7:52:56 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170912  7:52:56 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 4603050230
170912  7:52:56  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 4603057481
170912  7:52:57  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
170912  7:52:57  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
170912  7:52:58 InnoDB: 5.5.55 started; log sequence number 4603057481
170912  7:52:58 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
170912  7:52:58 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
170912  7:52:58 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
170912  7:52:58 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
170912  7:52:58 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.55-0+deb8u1-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Debian)
170912  7:53:06 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
170912  7:53:06 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170912  7:53:06 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170912  7:53:06 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
170912  7:53:06 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170912  7:53:06 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 300.0M
InnoDB: mmap(321945600 bytes) failed; errno 12
170912  7:53:06 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170912  7:53:06 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
170912  7:53:06 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
170912  7:53:06 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
170912  7:53:06 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
170912  7:53:06 [ERROR] Aborting

170912  7:53:06 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

If I increase the buffer pool size, the server goes down even sooner.

Comment: I see you have an error 12 when initializing buffer pool. The problem is that the server does not have enough memory to allocate for MySQL process. I see a lot of advice online, when googling this problem.

Comment: Yes. it happens after a day correctly work. why it try to get more 300M, if mysql already work full day?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  Memory allocation advice:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

Comment: I guess some other processes are using RAM on your server. They weren't running before, or weren't using so much RAM before. That would explain why MySQL can't get the RAM it needs now, even thought it worked before. Try using `top` to find out which processes are using so much RAM.

Answer (score 0):

This error:
**170912  7:53:06 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the bufferpool**

tells you that you have insufficient Buffer pool size to start InnoDB.

Edit `/etc/MySQL/my.cnf`
If it is not I that dir, then do `find / -name my.cnf`

search for `innodb_buffer_pool_size =`

Decrease the value you currently have to something like less than 50% of your ram.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20M`

Alternatively, you could start MySQL by skipping innodb.

`sudo -u mysql mysqld --skip-innodb --default-storage-engine=myisam`

Comment: But why its happens after day correctly mysql work?
I understand if it happens immediately after mysql start.
But the less innodb_buffer_pool_size, than mysql longer work correctly.

Comment: Number of threads starting perhaps? let's see that `my.cnf` file.

Comment: how much ram is on that server?

Comment: can you decrease the value to `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 50M` ?

Comment: On server 2GB RAM

Comment: ok, so let's see how it goes now with the pool size reduction.

Comment: Is not is to little? I read that innodb_buffer_pool_size should be more than 50% of server RAM

Comment: That is what we are testing, we need to see if that will help save the memory. What is the OS?

Comment: No, its crached. 
OS: Debian Jessie

Comment: Started hard lags, i return innodb_buffer_pool_size to 300M

Comment: You will nees to see what ia eating the memory. Do ps -ef and dump it every hour since starting mysql. Then have a look what causes high memory usages.